# thymeleaf post controller path variable

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I need to make post request with thymeleaf but have some problems
My controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/{project}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView index(@PathVariable Project project) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List<Task> findAll = taskService.findAll(project);
    modelAndView.addObject("findAllTasks", findAll);
    final String currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    modelAndView.addObject("user", userService.findByEmail(currentUser));
    modelAndView.setViewName("tasks");
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView createNewProject(@Valid Task task, BindingResult bindingResult, @PathVariable ("id") int id ) {
    Project project = projectService.findOne(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("id", id);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("tasks");
    } else {
        taskService.create(task, project);
        modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Task has been added succesfully");
        modelAndView.addObject("task", new Task());
        modelAndView.setViewName("tasks");
        List<Task> findAll = taskService.findAll(project);
        modelAndView.addObject("findAllTasks", findAll);
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

my html

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{'/tasks/' + ${id}}"
      th:object="${task}" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
      role="form">
    <input type="text" id="taskTitle" name="Title"  th:placeholder="Title"
           class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" id="body" name="body"  th:placeholder="text"
           class="form-control" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="public_feedback"
           class="form-control" /><label for="public_feedback">Public feedback</label>
    <span th:utext="${successMessage}"></span>
    <button type="submit" class="add">Add task</button>
</form>
```

but my post request is http://localhost:8080/tasks/null. Get request working is good. and hardcoding for example like

```
th:action="@{/tasks/1}"
```

working well but i need take path for current project
i need get project id by path variable by i can't find any answers. Help me please.

Comment: Try with `th:action="@{|/tasks/${task.id}|}"`

Comment: Instead of reading from Path Varibale for a POST request, try to bind the projectId attribute in the task object itself and read it.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `action` attribute in `<form>` with `th:action="@{|/tasks/${task.id}|}"`

I believe there is an `id` property with each `task`

Answer (score 0):

Do you iterate over each task within your html? You add a List of tasks (called findAllTasks) to the view so make sure you are using the correct object when posting the form. Otherwise there won't be an id.

You can put a already existing task (with an id) in your view and use that id when you post your form, or if you would like to create a new "task" with your post request just remove the id and wait for your repository to generate one when the object is created.